# Using DBNullable Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbnull

Here's the code:

```
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<STATbatter> completelist = new List<STATbatter>();
    DALbatter batter = new DALbatter();
    batter.NameLast = txtLastName.Text;

    DataTable batters = DALbatter.getBattersByLastName(batter);

    for (int i = 0; i < batters.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow bat = batters.Rows[i];

        STATbatter stat = new STATbatter();

        stat.PlayerID = bat.Field<String>("playerID");
        stat.G = bat.Field<Int32>("G");
        stat.Ab = bat.Field<Int32>("AB");
        stat.H = bat.Field<Int32>("H");
        stat.Bb = bat.Field<Int32>("BB");
        stat.Cs = bat.Field<Int32>("CS");
        stat.Doub = bat.Field<Int32>("2B");
        stat.Trip = bat.Field<Int32>("3B");
        stat.Hr = bat.Field<Int32>("HR");
        stat.Rbi = bat.Field<Int32>("RBI");
        stat.Sb = bat.Field<Int32>("SB");
        stat.K = bat.Field<Int32>("SO");
        stat.Ibb = bat.Field<Int32>("IBB");
        stat.Hbp = bat.Field<Int32>("HBP");
        stat.Sh = bat.Field<Int32>("SH");
        stat.Sf = bat.Field<Int32>("SF");
        stat.Gidp = bat.Field<Int32>("GIDP");

        //calculated fields
        stat.NameFull = STATbatter.fullName(bat.Field<String>("nameLast"), bat.Field<String>("nameFirst"));
        stat.Avg = STATbatter.battingAverage(stat.H, stat.Ab);
        stat.Obp = STATbatter.onBasePercentage(stat.Ab, stat.H, stat.Bb, stat.Hbp, stat.Sf);
        stat.Slg = STATbatter.slugging(stat.H, stat.Doub, stat.Trip, stat.Hr, stat.Ab);

        completelist.Add(stat);
    }

    gvBatters.DataSource = completelist;
    gvBatters.DataBind();
}
```

Here's the problem:

I attached an mdf file to the project in the App_Data file, created a connection string to use the local mdf. it was working just fine. I took the project to another PC, and on the line:

```
stat.Cs = bat.Field<Int32>("CS");
```

I get

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.

not sure why this worked perfectly on the other PC, but nonetheless, how can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column CS in the database can be null, so that you shouldn't use that reader to get `int` values. Use [NullableDataReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12778/C-2-0-Nullable-Data-Readers) instead to get the `int?` type. The use would be very similar:

```
stat.Cs = dr.GetNullableInt32("CS");
```

Comment: I am going to look at working this nullable data reader into my project.  thanks.

Comment: however, after trying so, it still seems the problem lies with my implicit conversion of the ints coming from the db to decimals in my class, make sense?

Comment: In the code you show, STATbatter should act as a `bean` and get the same fields of the database keeping their same types. If the column `CS` is `float`, use `GetNullableFloat` to populate STATbatter's `stsat.Cs` property. If it really is `int` and you perform a bad conversion in any other part, keep an eye on it and make a proper `System.Convert` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The value in your database in the CS column for that record is null. You can do one of two things: either fill in a value in the database, or modify your `STATbatter` class and set the `Cs` field to an `int?` instead of an `int`, which is a [nullable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx).

Comment: oh man,  i had it as an int because in the db it is an int, but i perform a lot of calculations on them and therefore needed them to be decimals,  so i just changed them all to decimals... this was the first test.  thanks, i can work around that.  will like your answer when the 10 mins is up